# How to open Chrome Browser in Ubuntu with chromedriver in Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I am working in developmenting a web app with next configuration:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Chromedriver 87.0.4280.88
- Chrome 87.0.4280.88 (Build oficial) (64 bits)
- Selenium 3.7.1 Java openjdk version "1.8.0_275"

Using chromedriver, in Windows, Chrome browser opens normally. But in Ubuntu (my production enviroment) it doesn't.
I know that using flag *--headless* chrome runs normally but it'snt a valid solution because I need GUI.
Without headless flag Chrome crashed.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-58-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_275'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x55dbd6829e79 <unknown>
```

As I read, I run my aplication with no-root user, so, I understand that Chrome tries to open with no-root user too.
Also I have tried using flags --sandbox y --disable-dev-shm-usage without success.

Please, any solution. Thanks